# Filtering xUnit Tests in pipeline AzureDevops

Tags: c#, azure-devops, xunit

I dont seem to be getting the filtering right and I am running tests I dont want to run.

I have

```
      MySolution  (Solution)
        MyProjectA.Tests
            AAA.Tests
            BBB.Tests
        MyProjectB.Tests
            AAA.Tests
```

Task in devops

```
      - task: VSTest@2
        displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
        inputs:    
          testAssemblyVer2: |
            **\bin\${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}\**\*Tests*.dll           
            !**\obj\**
            !**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll
            !**\xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll
          platform: '${{ parameters.buildPlatform }}'
          configuration: '${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}'
          searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'        
          otherConsoleOptions: '/platform:x64 /Framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1 /logger:console;verbosity="normal" '
```

I need to understand how I can

- run only tests belonging to MyProjectA
- run just BBB.Tests in MyProjectA

How do I do that? what do I need to change?

Many thanks

Comment: Either you can exclude MyProjectB tests using negate condition like `!**\bin\${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}\**\MyProjectB.Tests*.dll` or include only project A using `**\bin\${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}\**\MyProjectA.Tests*.dll`. In the later case remove `**\bin\${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}\**\*Tests*.dll  `

Comment: @user1672994 thanks for your prompt reply. so can you have 2 like this  **\bin\${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}\**\*Tests*.dll  !**\bin\${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}\**\*MyProjectB.Tests*.dll  will the above run only MyProjectA.Tests?

Comment: Yes, it should work that too. However, *** is not correct. it should be either ** or *. Check the pattern here -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hi friend, please check if the several answers below can resolve your issue. If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `testFiltercriteria` property on `VSTest@2` task which refer to `TestCaseFilter`

[image]

```
Run tests that match the given expression.

<Expression> is of the format <property>=<value>[|<Expression>].

Example: /TestCaseFilter:"Priority=1"

Example: /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=Nightly|FullyQualifiedName=Namespace.ClassName.MethodName" Warning: The /TestCaseFilter command line option cannot be used with the /Tests command line option.

For information about creating and using expressions, see TestCase filter.
```

So in you case it could be

```
FullyQualifiedName=~MyProjectA
```

and

```
FullyQualifiedName=~MyProjectA.Tests.BBB
```

For more details about filtering pleace take a look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/filter.md)

Comment: @developer9969 Can you consider upvoting my reply if it were helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

> run only tests belonging to MyProjectA

You could specify the project name in the test files:

```
- task: VSTest@2
        displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
        inputs:    
          testAssemblyVer2: |
            **\MyProjectA.Tests\bin\${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}\**\*Tests*.dll           
            !**\obj\**
            ...
```

> run just BBB.Tests in MyProjectA

You could use the `Test filter criteria` to filter the tests from BBB.Tests:

```
- task: VSTest@2
        displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
        inputs:    
          testAssemblyVer2: |
            **\MyProjectA.Tests\bin\${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}\**\*Tests*.dll           
            !**\obj\**
            testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=BBB'
            ...
```